# Characteristic Property for Products of Smooth Manifolds

Tags: category-theory, smooth-manifolds

Does the characteristic property for products of smooth manifolds hold as well:
$$f\text{ smooth}\iff \pi_i\circ f\text{ smooth ...where }f:M\to\prod_{i\in I} M_i\text{ and }\pi_i:\prod_{i\in I} M_i\to M_i$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is: YES!!! =D**

Before we start off we define charts on finite(!) products of manifolds in the obvious way (*obvious!*)...

Now, observe that the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable (*tricky!*).
 This immediately implies the analogue for manifolds.
Besides, note that projection functions are differentiable (*easy!*); so its analogue for manifolds.

These two observations imply that the components of differentiable functions are differentiable; mutatis mutandis for manifolds.

Conversely, it follows that differentiable components of finite(!) products give rise to differentiable functions (*doable!*); this again immediately implies the analogue for manifolds.

Concluding that a function is differentiable iff its components are differentiable; mutatis mutandis for manifolds.

**Especially, applying this to the original problem the answer is 'yes':

The product of manifolds satisfyies the characteristic property for smooth manifolds.**